# optimize multiple executions of grep

Tags: shell, grep

I have 3 files (links_file, my_links and my_queue) and I'm doing 3 things with the links_file:

- remove lines that have duplicate information (not all the line is to be checked, only a part of it, in the code bellow it is the var img_url). Keep the first line with the img_url
- remove lines where the img_url string exists in my_links file
- remove lines where the img_url string exists in my_queue file

I have working code, but it is taking a long time (more than 10 minutes) for around 30.000 lines in links_file, 1.000 in the my_links file and 300 in my_queue file.

```
function clean_file(){
    links_file="$1"
    my_links="$2"
    my_queue="$3"
    out_file="$4"

    rm -rf "$out_file"
    prev_url=""
    cat "$links_file" | while read line
    do
        img_url=$(echo $line | perl -pe 's/[ \t].*//g' | perl -pe 's/(.*)_.*/$1/g')
        # $links_file is sorted by img_url, so i can just check the previous value
        test "$prev_url" = "$img_url" && echo "duplicate: $img_url" && continue
        prev_url="$img_url"
        test $(grep "$img_url" "$my_links" | wc -l) -ne 0 && echo "in my_links: $img_url" && continue
        test $(grep "$img_url" "$my_queue" | wc -l) -ne 0 && echo "in my_queue: $img_url" && continue
        echo "$line" >> "$out_file"
    done
}
```

I'm trying to optimize the code, but ran out of ideas. My knowledge of perl is limited (I typically only use it for simple regular expressions replacement). Any help to optimize this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's do it step by step.

First, no need to call Perl twice. Instead of `img_url=$(echo $line | perl -pe 's/[ \t].*//g' | perl -pe 's/(.*)_.*/$1/g')`, you can just do

```
img_url=$(echo $line | perl -pe 's/[ \t].*//g;s/(.*)_.*/$1/g')
```

But then, we can combine the two regex' together:

```
s/.*_([^ \t]*).*/$1/
```

(find a group of non-empty characters following an underscore)

Also, Perl is an overkill where `sed` suffices:

```
img_url=$(echo $line | sed "s/.*_\([^ \t]*\).*/\1/")
```

But hey, maybe Perl should be actually your method of choice. You see, for every url read you read the two files (queue and links) in their entirety to find a matching line. If only there was a way of reading them and keeping the inventory in memory! Ohwait. Yes, we could do it in bash. No, I would not like to do it :-)

The Perl script below is neither particularly complex nor optimized, but should be way faster than your approach. And I tried to make it easy to understand; actually, above certain level (and you are definitely on that level), Perl is *much* simpler to write than bash.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict   ;
use warnings ;

my $my_links = "my_links" ;
my $my_queue = "my_queue" ;
# define the regular expression to find the img_url
my $regex = '.*_([^\s]*).*' ;

my %links = geturls( $my_links ) ;
my %queue = geturls( $my_queue ) ;

# loop over STDIN trying to find the match

my %index ;
while( <STDIN> ) {
  next unless m/$regex/ ; # ignore lines that do not match
  next if( $links{$1} || $queue{$1} || $index{$1} ) ; 
  $index{$1}++ ; # index hash to eliminate duplicates
  print $_ ;
} 

# function to store the two files (my_links and my_queue) in the memory.
# we populate a hash with the img urls read.
sub geturls {

  my $fname = shift ;
  my %ret ; 

  open my $fh, $fname or die "Cannot open $fname" ;

  while( <$fh> ) {
    next unless m/$regex/  ; # ignore lines that do not match
    # $1 holds the subexpression within the parentheses
    $ret{$1}++ ; 
  } 

  return %ret ;
}
```

The script will remove any duplicates, even those not on consecutive lines -- hope you don't mind.

One caveat, though: I assumed that all files follow a similar structure. Please provide example files and desired output next time you ask a question here.

Comment: I'm currently looking at you perl script. But the replacement of perl with sed and some other small changes got me an improvement of around 50%. Thank you. Your original combined regular expression is slightly off. I used img_url=$(echo "$line" | sed "s/\([^  ]*\)_.*/\1/g") (there is a TAB after the space, sed doest seem to like \t - at least in osx)

Comment: wow, it is amazingly fast. it takes less than 1 sec. I still need to compare the results with my old script, but so far it looks great.

Comment: Do that by all means! I have tested it with dummy files that I created based on your description, and anyway I slapped together a script without properly testing it. Yes, Perl or Python will be much faster than bash, esp. repeatedly grepping the files.